# After adding [(ngModel)] to a radio button group, the default [checked] no longer works

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm working on a small reusable Component which styles radio buttons and emits the selected values.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'button-select',
    template: `<div class="toggle-group">
                    <div *ngFor="let choice of choices">
                        <input type="radio"
                               id="{{ groupName + choice }}"
                               name="{{groupName}}"
                               value="{{ choice }}"
                               [checked]="choice === defaultChoice"
                               [(ngModel)]="value"
                               (ngModelChange)="choose($event)" />
                        <label class="toggle-button"
                               for="{{ groupName + choice }}">{{ choice }}</label>
                    </div>
                </div>`,
    styleUrls: [
        'editableField.css',
        'buttonSelect.css'
    ]
})

export class ButtonSelectComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() choices: string[];
    @Input() defaultChoice: string;
    @Input() groupName: string;
    @Input() value: string;

    @Output() valueChosen: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.choose(this.defaultChoice);
    }

    private choose(value: string) {
        this.valueChosen.emit(value);
    }
}
```

The component is implemented like so:

```
<button-select #statusFilter
               [choices]="['All', 'Active', 'Draft']"
               [defaultChoice]="'All'"
               [groupName]="'statusFilter'"
               (valueChosen)="filterChosen('statusFilter', $event)"
</button-select>
```

*Before* adding `[(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="choose($event)"` to the button-select Component, the `[checked]="choice === defaultChoice"` directive correctly set the `checked` attribute on the relevant `<input />`.

*After* adding the `[(ngModel)]`, *only* `ng-reflect-checked="true"` gets set, which prevents the visual styling from showing the default value (since my CSS uses a pseudo-selector).

Changing `[(ngModel)]` for `[ngModel]` had no effect.

**Why did this happen and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Short notice to the name attribute which you used: ```name="{{groupName}}"``` won't encapsulate your radio-group. You will be able to navigate to another radio-button in another radio-group on the same page using your arrow-keys once you tab to any radio-group. The reason is that Angular won't add the ```name``` attribute itself but ```ng-reflect-name```.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think, you don't need this `[checked]="choice === defaultChoice"`. Try this :

```
<input type="radio"
       id="{{ groupName + choice }}"
       name="{{groupName}}"
       [value]="choice"
       [(ngModel)]="defaultChoice"
       (ngModelChange)="choose($event)" />
```

When `[value] = [(ngModel)]` the radio is selected.

Comment: This is exactly correct! I had added `[checked]` early on before thinking to add the `[(ngModel)]` and never questioned it. Thank you.

Comment: @mickdev and @msanford i have exact same problem that my psudeo css `(input:checked)` is not applied. the surprising fact is the exact same code is working in other angular project. this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kaf2tp?file=src/rating/rating/rating.component.ts) is also working, which is replica, but i am not sure why my project do not show the 3 hightlights, when i inspect at both page (from different project) i see that ng-reflect-model is not added in my buggy project. please help

Comment: square brackets on [value]="3" worked for me when ngModel is using number instead of string

Answer (score 4):

I was able to emit the value and retain the default styling with minimal changes by altering the input's template to:

```
<input type="radio"
       id="{{ groupName + choice }}"
       name="{{groupName}}"
       value="{{ choice }}"
       [checked]="choice === defaultChoice"
       (click)="choose($event['target']['value'])" />
```

...which I find kind of hacky. It also doesn't explain why adding data/property binding broke it, so I'm open to more suggestions.

Comment: Using click to handle radiobuttons is a pretty bad suggestion. At least because clicking is not the only way to switch radiobutton. One can also do it with keyboard. Better use "change" event if you don't want `ngModel` for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

```js
export class ConfirmationmodalComponent implements OnInit {
  client_notification: any = false;
  candidate_notification: any = false;
  cancel_associated_session: any = false;

  constructor(
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input
    class="form-check-input"
    type="radio"
    id="inlineRadio1"
    name="cancel_associated_session"
    [(ngModel)]="cancel_associated_session"
    [value]="true"
  />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">
    Yes
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input
    class="form-check-input"
    type="radio"
    id="inlineRadio2"
    name="cancel_associated_session"
    [(ngModel)]="cancel_associated_session"
    [value]="false"
  />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">
    No
  </label>
</div>
```