# How to pass value for radio button in reactive form?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the RC5 version of Angular2
I have something like this, a few of them

`<input formControlName="uploadType" id="upload_type-parts_service" name="uploadType" value="parts_service" type="radio" />`

There is a onchange I bound

```
(change)=onUploadTypeChange( ??? )
```

Then I defined the function in my js

```
onUploadTypeChange( uploadType ) {
    this.uploadType = ...
}
```

I am having the hardest time trying to get the radio button value. My plan is to pass it to the onchange function and update the `uploadType` value which show/hide certain elements in the view. 
I have tried passing `this` or `this.value` or `this.type.controls.uploadType.value` but nothing works. `type` is the form itself.

Can someone please point out how I would get the value in reactiveforms?

Comment: [Maybe this article can help](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive)

Comment: @DomeTune I read that one but there is no radios in it. As a matter of fact, I can't find good sources on reactiveform radio handling

Comment: Check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443903/after-adding-ngmodel-to-a-radio-button-group-the-default-checked-no-longe/42446746

Comment: @msanford Ok I passed `$event` and was able to get the value which is great, however when I tried to print `{{ this.type.controls.uploadType.value }}` it does not print anything. I know this works because the initial value works. What could be causing this?

Comment: @Huangism Can you update the question with your new code? :)

Comment: @msanford I just figured it out, I will post an answer, your question did help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for msanford's question in comments, I figured out that `$event` needed to be passed

```
onUploadTypeChange( $event )
```

then in my js

```
onUploadTypeChange( e ) {
    this.uploadType = e.target.value;
}
```

The `target` returns the input itself

I was binding the value of the radio with `[value]=...` but this was not needed for reactiveforms and it was causing issues. I set values with just `values="..."`

Now everything works, and `{{ this.type.controls.uploadType.value }}` prints the expected value

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?  This watches for value changes and places the subscribe in the ngAfterViewInit() method.

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': displayMessage.Repeatable }">
      <label class="control-label" for="Repeatable">Repeatable</label>
      <input type="radio" id="Repeatable" [checked]="checked" 
          formControlName="Repeatable" />{{repeatableValue | uppercase}}              
</div>

// Component

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit');

    this.setForm.get('Repeatable').valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.repeatableValue = value.toString());
}
```

Comment: I did not try this because I didn't want to use subscribe. I don't think it is needed in my case, but thanks for the input