# I want to get the value of a radio button with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to get the value my radio buttons specifically the one that has been selected. I did try to do it through the following code:
my home.component.html

```
<span>Categories</span>
        <input type="button" onclick="alert($('input[name=category]:checked').attr('id'))" value="click me too" />
      <div id="categorybox">
      <tr  class="categories" *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <td>
          <input type="radio"  id={{category.category}} name="category" value="{{category}}"/>
          <label for ={{category.category}} >{{category.categoryName}}</label>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </div>
```

I am getting undefined  in the pop up and I am not sure why. I want to use the id to pass information to a http request so that I can get my products to display by category. I wanted it to be linked to my categories list from my api so that when I add a category it will already be displayed as a radio button . I just need to get that value through my function. The code is in the html for better readability.**I want to get the value of the button the one button whenever it's clicked.**

my home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Home} from '../model/Home';
import {HomeService} from '../service/Home.service';
import {Category} from '../model/Category';
import {CategoryService} from '../service/Category.service';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  page= 0;
  home: Home[];
  categories: Category[];

  constructor(private homeService: HomeService,private categoryService: CategoryService) { }

    Category($event){


    }


  SortPrice($event:any){
    let icon = document.getElementById("asc-desc1");
    if(icon.className === "fas fa-angle-down"){
      icon.className ="fas fa-angle-up";
      this.homeService.getByPriceAsc().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
    }else{
      icon.className ="fas fa-angle-down"
      this.homeService.getByPriceDesc().subscribe(data => {
        this.home = data;
      });
    };

  }

  SortSale($event:any){
    let icon = document.getElementById("asc-desc2");
    if(icon.className === "fas fa-angle-down"){
      icon.className ="fas fa-angle-up";
      this.homeService.getBySaleAsc().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
    }else{
      icon.className ="fas fa-angle-down"
      this.homeService.getBySaleDesc().subscribe(data => {
        this.home = data;
      });
    };

  }
  SortDiscount($event:any){
    let icon = document.getElementById("asc-desc3");
    if(icon.className === "fas fa-angle-down"){
      icon.className ="fas fa-angle-up";
      this.homeService.getByDiscountAsc().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
    }else{
      icon.className ="fas fa-angle-down"
      this.homeService.getByDiscountDesc().subscribe(data => {
        this.home = data;
      });
    };

  }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.homeService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
    this.categoryService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.categories = data;
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: You should be using `ngModel` in Angular to get the value of a selected radio button. Take a look at the example in the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443903/after-adding-ngmodel-to-a-radio-button-group-the-default-checked-no-longe

Comment: There's too much code here and it's not clear to me what it is you wish to do. It's not good to just dump a bunch of code here - you need to try to reproduce the problem first in a minimal example, so irrelevant code doesn't clutter the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the data of radio button.

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" name="category" value="{{category.category}}"
(change)="Category($event)"/>
```

Then capture the event in your TypeScript file; or you can use the model `selectedCategory`.

```
Category(value) {
    console.log(" Value is : ", value );
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I am not getting the value I am getting: Value is :  
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target: input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid..}

Comment: It seems you need to access the `target` member of the event object. In the printed event object, is there a member called `target` ?  

Can you try this method instead: `Category($event) {
     console.log($event.target.value);
}`

Comment: I am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in my console

Comment: What was the complete output you got previously?

Comment: Event {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target: input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid, currentTarget: input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid, eventPhase: 2, …}
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: (14) [input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched, td, tr.categories, div#categorybox, div#category.collapse.show, div.col-sm.main, div.row, div.container-fluid, app-home, app-root, body, html, document, Window]
returnValue: true
srcElement: input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched

Comment: target: input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched
timeStamp: 6075.5700001027435
type: "change"
__proto__: Event

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your radio and add a click event. Also, I think your name is not unique for your inputs.

In the TS :

```
<input type="radio"  id={{category.category}} [(ngModel)]=selectedCategory name="{{category.categoryName}}" value="{{category}}" (click)=selectCategory(category)/>
```

In the HTML :

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   public selectedCategory: Category

   public selectCategory (category) {
      // do something here
      // this.selectedCategory will be the selected value
      // the category will be the value that was just selected
   }
```

Comment: It works but it's selecting All of my buttons I don't want that. Is there away that it only selects one button?It selects all the categories when I click one radio button. I only want to select 1 category. Category is unique because there is  only one category no duplicates. Right now with your answer it's selecting all my radio buttons.

Comment: It means you have something wrong with the model. I would probably use ids to save my value. So bind would become {{selectedCategoryId}} and value would be {{category.id}}