# Select a default radio button in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular. Need some help here. There are two radio buttons for two text fields:

```
<div class="col-1">
 <label class="radio-container mb-0 mt-1">&nbsp;
   <input id="Page_Color" name="Page_Color" type="radio" [(ngModel)]='Br.Page_IsGraphic'
                      [value]='false' (change)="updateRadioChangeValToObj('Page_IsGraphic','Page_IsGraphic','Page_GraphicName','Page_Color')">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
</div>


<div class="col-1">
   <label class="radio-container mb-0 mt-1">&nbsp;
      <input id="IsGraphic" name="IsGraphic" type="radio" (change)="updateRadioChangeValToObj('Page_IsGraphic','Page_Graphic','Page_GraphicName','PageColor')"
                         [(ngModel)]='Br.Page_IsGraphic' [value]='true'>
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
   </label>
 </div>
```

In `[(ngModel)]='Br.Page_IsGraphic'` Br.Page_IsGraphic value is either true or false and that is dynamic and based on that the radio button is getting checked i think.
If it's true then the second radio button gets selected and if it's false then the 1st one.
Now the 1st text field had to be removed as per the requirement and I want the second radio button to be always selected by default.
Br.Page_IsGraphic value should be set to true  before theis code gets executed for this to work? or is there another way.
I tried `[checked]="true"` and that did not work.

Comment: Question is unclear. Can you elaborate your problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443903/after-adding-ngmodel-to-a-radio-button-group-the-default-checked-no-longe maybe this might help

Comment: Dod you try setting simple checked just like for default radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have two radio button associated with two text field and want to show text fields based on radio buttons are checked or not

.html file

```
<input type="radio" [checked] = "isFirst === true" (change)="markFirst()"/> First
<input type="radio"  [checked] = "isSecond === true" (change)="markSecond()"/>Second
<br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="First" *ngIf="isFirst"/>
<br><br>

<input type="text" placeholder="Second" *ngIf="isSecond"/>
```

.ts file

```
export class AppComponent  {
  isFirst = false
  isSecond = false

  markFirst(){
    this.isFirst = true
   // this.isSecond = false If you want second to hide if one is shown
  }

  markSecond(){
    this.isSecond = true
   // this.isFirst = false If you want second to hide if one is shown
  }
}
```

Working link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkqvqz

Comment: I have edited my question. So, now i will have only one radio button and i want it to be always selected.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it selected the checkbox by default:

```
[(ngModel)]='Br.Page_IsGraphic' [value]='Br.Page_IsGraphic'>
```